# Fastest way to map the values of a timeseries dataframe from another timeseries dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have to timeseries dataframes:

```
from pandas import Timestamp

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:01:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:02:00')], columns = ['Peter', 'Adam'], data =[['A', 'C'], ['C', 'D']])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:01:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:01:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:01:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:01:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:02:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:02:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:02:00'), Timestamp('2023-12-22 00:02:00')], columns=['Level', 'Score'], data=[['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['A', 5], ['B', 6], ['C', 7], ['D', 8]])
```

```
>>> df1
                    Peter Adam
2023-12-22 00:01:00     A    C
2023-12-22 00:01:00     C    D

>>> df2
                    Level  Score
2023-12-22 00:01:00     A      1
2023-12-22 00:01:00     B      2
2023-12-22 00:01:00     C      3
2023-12-22 00:01:00     D      4
2023-12-22 00:02:00     A      5
2023-12-22 00:02:00     B      6
2023-12-22 00:02:00     C      7
2023-12-22 00:02:00     D      8
```

I wish to get

```
                    Peter Adam
2023-12-22 00:01:00     1    3
2023-12-22 00:01:00     7    8
```

I can do using for loop, either go through by columns of df1 with apply or something

I feel there is a transform I could do to achieve the values very fast.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Why is it `7, 8` in the expected output? are the timestamp for `df1` intentionally identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible option using [Indexing-lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) :

```
def lookup(df, name):
    idx, cols = pd.factorize(df[name])
    return df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
   
inter = df1.join(df2.pivot(columns="Level", values="Score"))

out = (inter.assign(**{n: inter.pipe(lookup, n)
         for n in df1.columns})[df1.columns])
```

NB : Your MRE seems broken. The second index of `df1` should be `2023-12-22 00:02:00`.

Output :

```
print(out)

                     Peter  Adam
2023-12-22 00:01:00      1     3
2023-12-22 00:02:00      7     8

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: omg it works and fast enough. Thanks